# D3.js: what is 'g' in .append("g") D3.js code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to `D3.js`, started learning today only

I looked the the [donut example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) and found this code

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

I searched for [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append), but did not understood what `.append("g")` is appending

Is it even `D3` specific?

Looking for guidance here

Comment: Good answers coming in below. Possible worth checking out the following youtube video from D3Vienno on grouping in D3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYuFy1j8SGs Actually, if you're starting out, the whole series is worth watching :-).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It appends a ['g' element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups) to the SVG. `g` element [is used to group SVG shapes together](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html), so no it's not d3 specific.

Comment: MDN documentation for javascript always enlightens: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g.

An experimental pen can be found here: https://codepen.io/ahujamoh/pen/brRpWM

Answer (score 25):

I came here from a d3 learning curve as well. As already pointed out this is not specific to d3, it is specific to svg attributes. Here is a really good tutorial explaining the advantages of svg:g (grouping).

It is not that different from the use case of "grouping" in graphical drawings such 
as ones you would do in a powerpoint presentation.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html

As pointed in above link: to translate you need to use translate(x,y):

> The `<g>-element` doesn't have x and y attributes. To move the contents
>   of a `<g>-element` you can only do so using the transform attribute,
>   using the "translate" function, like this: transform="translate(x,y)".